# HTML tel: link not working on iPhone when anonymous call code #31# is used

Tags: html, tel, salesforce-marketing-cloud

For my customer, we send out emails to technicians with an overview of their daily appointments. Every appointment referenced in the email contains a phone number of the customer. This should allow the technician to call the customer, but they want to call anonymously. Normally, this is feasible with a prefix of #31# but it's not working (the phone number is clickable, but the dialer is not opening). It looks like #31#0472363XXX, which works when I just call it from my iPhone. But it doesn't work with a tel: in front (which makes it clickable). Anyone that can help? I think it's a known issue (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

I've also tried to replace the # with %23 but doesn't work either.

Html code snippet:

`Bel op <a alias="0474704XXX" color:="" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="tel:%2331%230474704XXX" style="color:#808080;text-decoration:underline;" title="0474704XXX">0474704XXX</a> test &nbsp;`

Comment: Update: fixed ! [13:13] Jasmijn Bastiaansen
    Update: fixed <a href="tel:#31#0032474704XXX" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-linkindex="4"  rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">#31#003247470XXX</a>